# JerseyTest: how to bind to Set<Integer>

Tags: jersey, jersey-test-framework

When testing with JerseyTest, I am having trouble to bind to a:

```
@Inject
@SomeQualifier
private Set<Integer> aSet;
```

It works with the following binding:

```
bind(Collections.EMPTY_SET).to(Set.class).qualifiedBy(new SomeQualifierLiteral());
```

ONLY when the field is *without* the generic, e.g. private Set aSet;

How can I make a successful bind if a generic is present on the field definition?

Comment: What Jersey version?

Comment: 2.28 (jersey-core & jersey-hk2)

Comment: Are you using the Jersey `AbstractBinder` or the HK2 one? If the former, try to use `.to(new GenericType<Set<Integer>>(){})`. If the latter, try to use `.to(new TypeLiteral<Set<Integer>>(){})`

Comment: I am using AbstractBinder and GenericType<Set<Integer>>(){}  does work!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered by @PaulSamsotha in his comment.